# ffmpeg reduce mp4 size errors: 'Unknown encoder libx264' and 'Unable to find a suitable output format for'

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4

I am quite new to ffmpeg and video editing. I try to reduce the size of various mp4 files. I followed a pretty straightforward tutorial ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c-uKCAv3e9M)) and also copy the audio. In Terminal (Mac user) I write:

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.mp4 -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -crf 24 outputfile.mp4
```

The error here is: `Unknown encoder 'libx264'` and even when I omit the 'libx264' from the code above, it still gives me the following error: `[NULL @ 0x7f9a21814c00] Unable to find a suitable output format for '24' 24: Invalid argument`

As long as I know, 24 is a totally valid value for crf. Of course I tried with others (20, 14, 30) and the error is still there.

I would very much appreciate a bit of guidance. Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: Your ffmpeg binary is not linked to x264. Get a git build from https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Comment: Thank you @Gyan. I am using a Mac (updated in my post). Do you think it's a matter of updating ffmpeg? I got the 4.0 version already

Comment: It's about getting a ffmpeg build with x264 linked; not so much the version number, although it's always advisable to get the latest. Get a Mac build from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

Comment: @Gyan is correct, except they are linking to a Linux build. For Mac, install with homebrew. It has x264 enabled by default.